# Test on physical device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is it correct understood that I have to pay 99 USD before being able to my windows phone app on the physical device.
I have made a small app that I would like to test on my new phone, and it is not a app that I am planning to release, so I will not pay 99 USD just for seeing the app running a physical device.
Any way around not paying the 99 USD, and seeing it run on the device.

Comment: If you're a student and have access to DreamSpark, you can get a free AppHub account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right. 
'Till April 2012 there was also "Chevron" that officially (allowed by MSFT) unlocked your devices (only for testing on the device/sideloading, but not for submitting to marketplace), but this service is closed now. So the only official way is the MSFt subscription for 99$.