# Do i need developer account that costs 99$ to develop apps for my own Windows Phone?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

This is not a question about programming, but i hope i get answer.

**Do i need developer account that costs 99$ to develop apps for my own Windows Phone?**

Already I know that phone is locked and i can install apps only from Marketplace.

Are there any workarounds? I don't want to sell my app, i just need (for my own **Nokia Lumia 800**) to write some music player with editable playlist, because OEM players are totally useless for me.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873384/test-on-physical-device

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to test any app on your phone you need to get it unlocked by getting it registered under a developer account. You need not pay $99 if you have a `student` account on dreamspark. If you don't have that and are still you want to get it unlocked, get it registered under one of your developer friends who have the Dev aaccount.